# XML parsing with simplexml_load_string is not working

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to parse some data from XML file. I can parse data succesfully from XML file using below script.

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('xml/montreal.xml');
if ($sxe === false) {
   foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo $error->message . PHP_EOL;
}
} else {
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('h', 'http://schemas.example.com/webservices/hotelsdkfs');
$hotels = $sxe->xpath('//h:Hotel');
$rowF = '<li><div class="title">%s</div><div class="artist">by %s</div></li>'. PHP_EOL;
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $attr = $hotel->attributes();
    printf($rowF, $attr['name'], $attr['brandId']);
}   
}
?>
```

This script is working perfectly. But i need to work this parsing also using simplexml_load_string() function. I'm getting same XML content to a $response variable. Im using this script for that:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$sxe = simplexml_load_string($response);
if ($sxe === false) {
   foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo $error->message . PHP_EOL;
}
} else {
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('h', 'http://schemas.example.com/webservices/hotelsdkfs');
$hotels = $sxe->xpath('//h:Hotel');
$rowF = '<li><div class="title">%s</div><div class="artist">by %s</div></li>'. PHP_EOL;
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $attr = $hotel->attributes();
    printf($rowF, $attr['name'], $attr['brandId']);
}   
}
?>
```

But its not working. its showing error "Start tag expected, '<' not found". How I fix this?

my XML is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SearchHotelsResponse xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/hotelasdfcgjk">
        <SearchHotelsResult>
            <Info version="7.123" culture="en-US" serverTime="2017-03-01T07:31:08.9180701-05:00" xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/webservices/hotelasdlkjdft"/>
            <HotelList xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/webservices/hotelv3">
                <Hotel brandId="141" brandName="Days Inn" category="Moderate" PropertySubType="" NumOfRoom="123" minAverPublishPrice="113.37" PropertyType="Hotel" name="Chrome Hotel Downtown Montreal - Demo" bestValue="false" hotelId="11856" provider="localTgsProvider" thumb="http://image1.urlforimages.com/Images/11856/100x100/1852921506.jpg" currency="CAD" minAverPrice="113.37" starsLevel="3" desc="Demo - Location&#xD;&#xA;The hotel is located in the heart of Montreal's cultural and business district in the city centre, within walking distance of Old Montreal, major attractions, festivals, restaurants, bars, shops and nightlife. The Latin Quarter, conventio">
                    <Location countryCode="CA" stateCode="QC" city="Montreal" searchingState="Quebec" searchingCity="Montreal" location="Downtown Area" address="Demo - 215 Boulevard Rene-Levesque East Montreal Quebec H2X 1N7" longitude="-73.5602601037048" latitude="45.5110178771468"/>
                    <RoomTypes>
                        <RoomType NumOfBathrooms="0" roomTypeCategory="Standard" roomTypeCategoryId="17" nights="7" name="Standard" productId="11856;11182;9356" startDate="2017-03-20T00:00:00" hotelRoomTypeId="11182" roomId="3" isAvailable="true">
                            <AvailabilityBreakdown>
                                <Availability offset="0" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="1" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="2" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="3" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="4" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="5" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="6" status="true"/>
                            </AvailabilityBreakdown>
                            <Occupancies>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="126.7" avrNightPublishPrice="113.37" occupId="11856;11182;9356;2;2;0;1" occupPrice="793.59" tax="126.7" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="113.37" occupPublishPrice="793.59" isPublish="false" bedding="2,1">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="168.87" bbPublishPrice="168.87"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="126.7" avrNightPublishPrice="113.37" occupId="11856;11182;9356;2;2;0;2" occupPrice="793.59" tax="126.7" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="113.37" occupPublishPrice="793.59" isPublish="false" bedding="2,2">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="113.37" valuePublish="113.37"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="168.87" bbPublishPrice="168.87"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                            </Occupancies>
                        </RoomType>
                    </RoomTypes>
                </Hotel>
                <Hotel brandId="0" brandName="" category="Superior First Class" PropertySubType="" NumOfRoom="108" minAverPublishPrice="226.33" PropertyType="Hotel" name="Le Saint Sulpice Hotel Montreal - Demo" bestValue="false" hotelId="1035988" provider="localTgsProvider" thumb="http://image1.urlforimages.com/Images/1035988/100x100/1476355076.jpg" currency="CAD" minAverPrice="226.33" starsLevel="4" desc="Demo - Location&#xD;&#xA;This attractive and comfortable city hotel is situated in the most historic area of Montreal, behind the famous basilica of Notre-Dame. Links to the public transport network lie 5 minutes' walk away, and the immediate vicinity also featur">
                    <Location countryCode="CA" stateCode="QC" city="Montreal" searchingState="Quebec" searchingCity="Montreal" location="Old Montreal" address="Demo - 414 Rue Saint Sulpice Montreal Quebec H2Y 2V5" longitude="-73.5549658932541" latitude="45.5043900016175"/>
                    <RoomTypes>
                        <RoomType NumOfBathrooms="0" roomTypeCategory="Suite" roomTypeCategoryId="19" nights="7" name="Superior Suite" productId="1035988;1121945;28111" startDate="2017-03-20T00:00:00" hotelRoomTypeId="1121945" roomId="410" isAvailable="true">
                            <AvailabilityBreakdown>
                                <Availability offset="0" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="1" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="2" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="3" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="4" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="5" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="6" status="true"/>
                            </AvailabilityBreakdown>
                            <Occupancies>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="234.5" avrNightPublishPrice="226.33" occupId="1035988;1121945;28111;2;2;0;1" occupPrice="1584.31" tax="234.5" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="226.33" occupPublishPrice="1584.31" isPublish="false" bedding="2,1">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="277.14" bbPublishPrice="277.14"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="234.5" avrNightPublishPrice="226.33" occupId="1035988;1121945;28111;2;2;0;2" occupPrice="1584.31" tax="234.5" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="226.33" occupPublishPrice="1584.31" isPublish="false" bedding="2,2">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="226.33" valuePublish="226.33"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="277.14" bbPublishPrice="277.14"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                            </Occupancies>
                        </RoomType>
                        <RoomType NumOfBathrooms="0" roomTypeCategory="Deluxe" roomTypeCategoryId="9" nights="7" name="Deluxe Queen" productId="1035988;1956583;28111" startDate="2017-03-20T00:00:00" hotelRoomTypeId="1956583" roomId="315" isAvailable="true">
                            <AvailabilityBreakdown>
                                <Availability offset="0" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="1" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="2" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="3" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="4" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="5" status="true"/>
                                <Availability offset="6" status="true"/>
                            </AvailabilityBreakdown>
                            <Occupancies>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="270.55" avrNightPublishPrice="265.93" occupId="1035988;1956583;28111;2;2;0;1" occupPrice="1861.51" tax="270.55" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="265.93" occupPublishPrice="1861.51" isPublish="false" bedding="2,1">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="265.93" valuePublish="265.93"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="277.14" bbPublishPrice="277.14"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                                <Occupancy taxPublish="294.63" avrNightPublishPrice="292.32" occupId="1035988;1956583;28111;2;2;0;2" occupPrice="2046.24" tax="294.63" maxGuests="4" maxChild="2" avrNightPrice="292.32" occupPublishPrice="2046.24" isPublish="false" bedding="2,2">
                                    <PriceBreakdown>
                                        <Price offset="0" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="1" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="2" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="3" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="4" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="5" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                        <Price offset="6" value="292.32" valuePublish="292.32"/>
                                    </PriceBreakdown>
                                    <Rooms>
                                        <Room seqNum="1">
                                            <AdultNum>2</AdultNum>
                                            <ChildNum>0</ChildNum>
                                        </Room>
                                    </Rooms>
                                    <SelctedSupplements/>
                                    <BoardBases>
                                        <Boardbase bbId="1" bbName="Continental Breakfast" bbPrice="277.14" bbPublishPrice="277.14"/>
                                    </BoardBases>
                                </Occupancy>
                            </Occupancies>
                        </RoomType>
                    </RoomTypes>
                </Hotel>
            </HotelList>
        </SearchHotelsResult>
    </SearchHotelsResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Add please output `var_dump($response);` to question.

Comment: "I'm getting same XML content to a $response variable"  - based on the error, you're not. In fact, since it doesn't say it found something else instead, probably you've not actually defined `$response` at all.

Comment: I sure that content of xml file and `$response` are different. You can set your xml content to `$response` as text and check result. I mean: `$response = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">....</s:Envelope>';`